How to opt out specific packages of bundling
I want to opt specific packages out of bundling.

The documentation says:
/** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */
const nextConfig = {
  serverExternalPackages: ['package-name'],
}
 
module.exports = nextConfig

but the compiler says otherwise:
⚠ Invalid next.config.mjs options detected: 
⚠     Unrecognized key(s) in object: 'serverExternalPackages'
⚠ See more info here: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/invalid-next-config

I did try this, of course:
/** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */
const nextConfig = {
  serverExternalPackages: ['package-name'],
}
 
module.exports = nextConfig

but the compiler immediately throws an error.

Even the solution I tried previously was in the Nextjs documentation. Looks like serverExternalPackages is no longer a valid option for the Nextjs configuration.
To exclude certain packages from being bundle on the server-side, Nextjs provide the following way to handle package exclusions: Offloading the task to webpack!
/** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */
const nextConfig = {
    webpack: (config, { isServer }) => {
        if (isServer) {
            // Exclude packages from the server-side bundle
            config.externals.push('muhammara', '@mapbox/node-pre-gyp');
        }
        return config;
    },
}

export default nextConfig;


This worked for me with Sequelize. So dumb that the documentation doesn't reflect this!
